# can we add ci cd in new created branch at run time on dynamic Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, github, continuous-integration, firebase-hosting, github-actions

I want to deploy the current created branch code in firebase hosting using a dynamic unique deployment url.

I have found some tutorial that are adding trigger only on a specific branch like: master, staging and deployment.

But I want to deploy every new created branch code on a dynamic unique hosting url while pushing the code of new created branch.

I am using GitHub and firebase.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to accomplish this? I'm interested in doing branch-based deploys also.